# How to consume a SOAP Web service with arguments in Camel?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, apache-camel

We have struggled for sometime now with a Camel app where we need to connect to a web service using arguments in the SOAP message.
The web service in http://edw.morningstar.com/webservice/edw.asmx?op=UploadPrivateList accepts four parameters, ClientId, flag, filename and byte[].

Is there anyone who can shed some light to how we are supposed to create a route that works?

We've managed to connect but we can't set the SOAP envelope to contain the requested parameters. The reply from the web service should be true but we get false because of the SOAP content. We can't see the envelope sent either…

The service we are trying to use is **UploadPrivateList**.

Please advice!

Thx

/M

From web service:

```
POST /webservice/edw.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: edw.morningstar.com
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <UploadPrivateList xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ClientId>string</ClientId>
      <flag>string</flag>
      <fileName>string</fileName>
      <fs>base64Binary</fs>
    </UploadPrivateList>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <UploadPrivateListResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <UploadPrivateListResult>boolean</UploadPrivateListResult>
    </UploadPrivateListResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to use a Camel route for everything. You can use vanilla Apache CXF for calling a SOAP web service if you want to generate client skeleton code from a wsdl etc. Just like in the old days with Apache Axis.

From a Camel route you can use the camel-cxf component. You can use that with and without generated POJO classes for your web service. For that to work look at the dataFormat mode option on camel-cxf. As you can use it in PAYLOAD and MESSAGE mode that is not POJO based.

Also to call a plain SOAP web service you can also fallback and use plain HTTP component.

To use a Camel route or Camel endpoint from Java code, read the documentation about `ProducerTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the Apache CXF component for Camel http://camel.apache.org/cxf.html. You should investigate using a 'WSDL first ' approach (that term should give you lots of good search tips).

Essentially CXF provides tooling which convert the WSDL for your SOAP service (at http://edw.morningstar.com/webservice/edw.asmx?wsdl) into Java classes. Your Camel route then consists of some code to instantiate instances of these, then a use of the CXF component to make the SOAP call.

I strongly recommend the 'Camel in Action' book - I'm pretty sure it has a chapter which deals with exactly the scenario you describe (and uses the solution I mention)

Comment: I have tested CXF, I have read the book and I have tried camel-ws, camel-soap and camel-cxf with no luck. No examples found on the net :(

Comment: The closest example I have seen is this: https://code.google.com/p/camel-soap/wiki/Introduction, but it fails also

Comment: 7.4.2 "Using a contract-first approach" in the book covers this use case. I recommend following the steps mentioned. If/when it  doesn't work  then post a follow up questions detailing what exactly doesn't work. camel-cxf *is* a good fit for this use case.

Comment: I hadn't come across camel-soap before. camel-cxf has a bit of overhead to get going (especially if you aren't already using Maven)

Comment: Almost all examples are *from* a web service. I'm *to* a web service. Using maven…

Comment: Have generated the proxy and all Java objects from wsdl bit can't figure out how to map them into the route(s)

Comment: Both the book and the Camel docs cover setting this up using Spring (`<cxf:cxfEndpoint...>`. You then just use `<to uri="cxf:..."`).